# Grounding question

Tags: ground

Say you have a DC circuit that is powered by a 9V battery. Can you connect the ground side of that DC circuit (like the negative side of an electrolytic capacitor, the cathode of an LED and so on) to something like a ground pole in a building instead of the negative terminal of the battery, and have the circuit still work?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking.  In a battery powered circuit with no connection to anything else, you can designate any node (ie point) of the circuit to be "ground" and connect it to a pole in the earth.  However, a bunch of connections that do not form a closed path do not constitute a *circuit* - so for example if you connect to only the positive terminal of a battery and leave nothing connecting to the negative, then that battery is not part of a circuit and is "not really doing anything" but sitting there and slowly aging, just as it would sitting on the supply shelf.

Comment: There is 9 volts across terminals of the battery, not the positive terminal and ground. I think technically, the meaning of "ground" (not meaning earth-ground or such), is arbitrary. It's just chosen for convenience when analizing circuits.

Comment: @KamilJarosz - you have to be careful stating that voltages (potential differences) exist in some places and not others.  In reality there are voltages of hundreds, even thousands of volts between unconnected objects - for example a 1 meter difference in altitude typically means a 100 volt potential difference.  But the *impedance* (resistance) is so high that essentially no current can be drawn beyond that which can activate very sensitive meters.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Right, it's good to clarify. I did not mean to imply there is no voltage between the positive terminal of the battery and some other arbitrary point. I merely wanted to state, that the rating "9V" applies strictly to the voltage between the negative terminal and the positive terminal in normal circumstances. That does not rule out that there may be some other potential between other points.

Comment: The problem is that you're still thinking in terms of *voltage* and not in terms of *circuits*.   A 9v battery (or any other) can't usefully power a *circuit* unless it is part of that circuit, ie, unless there is a complete path from one terminal, through the load portion of the circuit, and back to the other terminal.

Comment: I'm really confused what point you're trying to make.

Comment: No. Ground is not magic. But it is complicated to explain partly because there is a lot of misinformation out there. Electrical current always flows in a circuit. Ground is just a name we give to one "node" in the circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, something like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRubk3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, that will work. You need proper grounding of both the battery and the load on one pole. The internal resistance of a 9V battery is rather high, which means both grounds have to be *excellent*. Copper nets of several square meters each in wet soil.

Comment: But why doesn't current flow when you connect the + side of a battery to the - side of a different battery?It's still a voltage potential though not in the same object?

Comment: @Atila, notice that in Janka's answer both the battery and the load are connected to ground, meaning that are connected to each other. If you don't connect the battery to ground, it will not work, because there won't be a circuit formed.

Comment: Having another battery connected to ground but not to the load is irrelevant.  It won't affect this circuit in any way.

Comment: Yes by saying " connected to ground" i mean both the battery and the load..

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it will work. However, it makes no sense to connect any terminal of your flashlight to earth.

Comment: The original question asked " instead of the negative terminal".  It won't work unless it's connected to the negative terminal.

Comment: But it also said the circuit is already powered by a battery so I expect the light be on, and connecting ground pole to anywhere in the flashlight makes no sense. Connecting one bulb wire to battery and other bulb wire to ground pole obviously does not work.